# GEE Sentinel 2 Image error: expected a homogeneous image collection, but an image with an incompatible band was encountered

Tags: google-earth-engine, sentinel-2

```
var roi = ee.FeatureCollection("users/sevki/izmir"),
var img2017= ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_SR")
      .filterDate('2017-1-1', '2018-1-1')
      .filterMetadata('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 'less_than', 5)
      .filterBounds(roi)
      .median()
      .select('B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B8', 'B11', 'B12')
      .clip(roi)
      .divide(10000);
    print(img2017, 'Image 2017');
```

it worked yesterday but today I got the error message:

> Expected a homogeneous image collection, but an image with
> incompatible bands was encountered:
>
> First image type: 23 bands (`[B1, B2, B3, B4, B5, B6, B7, B8, B8A, B9, B11, B12, AOT, WVP, SCL, TCI_R, TCI_G, TCI_B, MSK_CLDPRB, MSK_SNWPRB, QA10, QA20, QA60]`).
>
> Current image type: 21 bands (`[B1, B2, B3, B4, B5, B6, B7, B8, B8A, B9, B11, B12, AOT, WVP, SCL, TCI_R, TCI_G, TCI_B, QA10, QA20, QA60]`).
>
> Image ID: `20170403T090021_20170403T090840_T35SNC`
>
> Some bands might require explicit casts.

Comment: I'm unable to replicate this. You haven't specified `roi`, perhaps it's only showing up for some specific area. Update your question and include it.

Comment: I've just updated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking the metadata for the two incompatible bands (MSK_CLDPRB, MSK_SNWPRB), these two might be missing in some images. I am sure there would be better solutions but a quick one might be to avoid these bands by just using the select argument first
[image]

```
var img2017= ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_SR")
      .select('B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B8', 'B11', 'B12')
      .filterDate('2017-1-1', '2018-1-1')
      .filterMetadata('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 'less_than', 5)
      .filterBounds(roi)
      .median()
      .clip(roi)
      .divide(10000);
    print(img2017, 'Image 2017');
```

Answer (score 0):

We are updating all images in this collection to have MSK bands (which might be empty). This is almost done, but meanwhile such errors might indeed occur.

Answer (score -1):

```
var dataset = ee.FeatureCollection("users/mpangihutan/Jawa Tengah");

function maskS2clouds(image) {
  var qa = image.select('ST_ATRAN');

  // Bits 10 and 11 are clouds and cirrus, respectively.
  var cloudBitMask = 1 << 10;
  var cirrusBitMask = 1 << 11;

  // Both flags should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions.
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0)
      .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cirrusBitMask).eq(0));

  return image.updateMask(mask).divide(10000);
}

// Load Landsat LC08 reflectance data.
var lc8 = ee.FeatureCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR')
                  .filterDate('2013-01-01', '2013-12-31')
                  .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUD_COVER',30))
                  .map(maskS2clouds)
                  .filter(ee.Filter.bounds(roi));

var visualization = {
  bands: ['SR_B4', 'SR_B3', 'SR_B2'],
  min: 0.0,
  max: 0.3,
};

// Proses Landsat LC08
var image = dataset.median(); 
var clipped = image.clip(roi)

var ndwi = clipped.normalizedDifference(['B3', 'B11']).rename(['ndwi']);

var tss = clipped.expression(
       "(ndwi > 0.1) ? 8.1429 * pow(VNIR,23.704* 0.94* Bandred))"+
       ": 0",{
         'ndwi' : ndwi,
         'VNIR': image.select('B7')
}).rename('tss');

var palete = ['blue','yellow','red','brown']

//print(maxTSS)

var vizTSS = {
  min: 1,
  max: 120,
  palette: palete
}

function createColorBar(titleText, palette, min, max) {
  // Legend Title
  var title = ui.Label({
    value: titleText, 
    style: {fontWeight: 'bold', textAlign: 'center', stretch: 'horizontal'}});

  // Colorbar
  var legend = ui.Thumbnail({
    image: ee.Image.pixelLonLat().select(0),
    params: {
      bbox: [0, 0, 1, 0.1],
      dimensions: '200x20',
      format: 'png', 
      min: 0, max: 1,
      palette: palette},
    style: {stretch: 'horizontal', margin: '8px 8px', maxHeight: '40px'},
  });
  
  // Legend Labels
  var labels = ui.Panel({
    widgets: [
      ui.Label(min, {margin: '4px 10px',textAlign: 'left', stretch: 'horizontal'}),
      ui.Label((min+max)/2, {margin: '4px 20px', textAlign: 'center', stretch: 'horizontal'}),
      ui.Label(max, {margin: '4px 10px',textAlign: 'right', stretch: 'horizontal'})],
    layout: ui.Panel.Layout.flow('horizontal')});
  
  // Create a panel with all 3 widgets
  var legendPanel = ui.Panel({
    widgets: [title, legend, labels],
    style: {position: 'bottom-left', padding: '8px 15px'}
  })
  return legendPanel
}
// Call the function to create a colorbar legend  
var colorBar = createColorBar('Total Suspended Soil / TSS - mg/liter', palete, 0, 120)

// Tayang peta2
//Map.addLayer(ndti, {}, 'NDTI');
//Map.addLayer(ndwi, {}, 'NDWI');
Map.add(colorBar)

    Export.image.toDrive({
  image: TSS_Masked,
  description: "tss",
  scale: 30,
  region: roi
})
```

Comment: A naked block of code does not make a useful Answer.  Much like the Question must explain the problem, the Answer should also use text to frame the solution.